# Update index modification in all my DataFrames Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm programming a "music database" with Pandas, using DataFrames, for a school project. To make research in my DataFrame easier and because my teacher asks me to, I created some secondary DataFrames which associate for example a musician in index with the index of all their compositions in value. In this application I want a 'delete' option where the user can delete a musical work and all its information, but when I do that it create a "hole" in the indexing, and I don't know how I can update index information in my `others` DataFrame

I searched in Pandas documentation, about using the `reindex` function to fill the hole, but when I'm doing that it updates all the index in my `main` DF and I don't know how I can update the index in my `other` DF either.

My `main` DF looks like this :

```
0     Requiem    Mozart      D minor
1     Symphony 9 Beethoven   D minor
2     Symphony 5 Beethoven   C minor
```

The `other` DF looks like :

```
Mozart       "0"
Beethoven    "1,2"
```

When I delete a music the `main` DF becomes:

```
0     Requiem    Mozart      D minor
2     Symphony 5 Beethoven   C minor
```

But It doesn't change my `other` DataFrame, and I don't know how I can update the `other` DataFrame with the new index of my `main` DataFrame.

(Apologies if my English is not perfect, it's my first post on this website and I'm French, thanks for your help.)

Comment: are you looking for `df.reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: It might help clarity a little if you renamed your dataframes `other` -> `composers`/`works` and  `main`  -> `piece`/`symphony`/whatever

Answer (score 0):

I think you need convert values to separate rows by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) - also dont forget convert values to `integer` by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) for match data:

```
print (df)
           a    b
0     Mozart    0
1  Beethoven  1,2

df2 = (df.join(df.pop('b')
                .str.split(',', expand=True)
                .stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
                .rename('b')
                .astype(int))).reset_index(drop=True)

print (df2)
           a  b
0     Mozart  0
1  Beethoven  1
2  Beethoven  2
```

So possible filter by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df22 = df2[df2['b'].isin(df1.index)]
```